# Complex query join using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I have a query which produce results in phpmyadmin but not in codeigniter.

```
$sql = "SELECT express_interests.*, 
       cl_to  .User_Name AS ToClient, 
       cl_from.User_Name AS FromClient,
       cl_from.Member_Id AS FromMid,
       cl_to.Member_Id AS ToMid

FROM express_interests  
    INNER JOIN users AS cl_to ON cl_to.User_Id = express_interests.To_Id
    INNER JOIN users AS cl_from ON cl_from.User_Id = express_interests.User_Id";
```

i want to use the same query in codeignitor. This is what i have used

```
$this->db->select('express_interests.*, 
       cl_to  .User_Name AS ToClient, 
       cl_from.User_Name AS FromClient,
       cl_from.Member_Id AS FromMid,
       cl_to.Member_Id AS ToMid
');

$this->db->from('express_interests');


$this->db->join('users AS cl_to', 'cl_to.User_Id = express_interests.To_Id');
$this->db->join('users AS cl_from', 'cl_from.User_Id = express_interests.User_Id');
```

when i use this it says

> Unknown column 'cl_to .User_Name' in 'field list'

what is the proper way to use the above query in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('express_interests.*, 
       cl_to  .User_Name AS ToClient, 
       cl_from.User_Name AS FromClient,
       cl_from.Member_Id AS FromMid,
       cl_to.Member_Id AS ToMid
');
```

Replace this with

```
$this->db->select('express_interests.*, 
       cl_to.User_Name AS ToClient, 
       cl_from.User_Name AS FromClient,
       cl_from.Member_Id AS FromMid,
       cl_to.Member_Id AS ToMid
');
```

Unwanted spacing in between table alias & column name

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
cl_to  .User_Name AS ToClient,
```

with

```
cl_to.User_Name AS ToClient,
```

or you can directly run sql statement in codeigniter as

```
$sql = "SELECT express_interests.*, 
   cl_to.User_Name AS ToClient,
   cl_from.User_Name AS FromClient,
   cl_from.Member_Id AS FromMid,
   cl_to.Member_Id AS ToMid

FROM express_interests  
INNER JOIN users AS cl_to ON cl_to.User_Id = express_interests.To_Id
INNER JOIN users AS cl_from ON cl_from.User_Id = express_interests.User_Id"; 

$result=$this->db->query($sql);

print_r($result->result());

die;
```